# calling love functions in lua

Tags: lua, love2d

I have installed lua using lua rocks and it works fine. Now I want to use the love libraries to do some graphics within my lua script. But I can't find any documentation on how to link love code to lua code... infact I am still confused as to the difference.

I am under the impression that love is a set of libraries for lua, but love seems to have its own binary for running...meaning it is its own language?

Anyway, here is my sad little attempt at writing a lua script using love:

myluatest.lua:

```
if "test" == "test" then print("yes") else print("no") end   
love.graphics.print('love test', 400, 300)
print(string.byte("ABCDE", 3, 4))
```

If I comment out the "love.graphics...." line it works fine. This is how I run the script:

`lua myluatest.lua`

I feel I need to include love or somthing, I just can't find the syntax :(

Comment: Löve isn't a set of libraries, it's a framework written in C++ that uses Lua (Luajit really) as its scripting language. In fact when working with Löve you just write a bunch of callback functions in Lua (like `love.load`, `love.update`, `love.draw`) which are then called and executed from the C++ code.

Comment: @user6245072 - I guess also that means you don't really need lua installed at all (since love has its own lua51.dll)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Love is not a library, there is nothing to include. Love is an application written in C++ that is scriptable with Lua. Love exposes its builtin graphics functions (written in C++) to the Lua environment using the C API. It also is the application driver, meaning that you can't run a Love application as you would a regular Lua one. You must fill in the callbacks, mentioned [here](https://love2d.org/wiki/Tutorial:Callback_Functions), then Love will automatically run them.

To make your script work you have to incorporate it into one of the callback functions. If you want some task to run once at the beginning of the application use `love.load()`, or if you want it to run continuously use `love.update()`. Only `love.draw()` can contain calls to love.graphics.draw methods.

```
function love.draw()
    if "test" == "test" then print("yes") else print("no") end   
    love.graphics.print('love test', 400, 300)
    print(string.byte("ABCDE", 3, 4))
end
```

Expect a lot of console output, draw() runs continuously.

Comment: ah ha, thanks very much!, I see - I have just updated my code - also I was still trying to run it with `lua filename`, but I spotted somewhere that you need to run the whole folder and use the "love.exe", like: `love folderpath`, AND your file has to be called main.lua. Is there a way to run a standalone file that is not called main.lua?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You can pass 'project files' which are essentially zipped up directories, but I don't think that helps you. I know some Lua IDEs like ZeroBrain run love for you, or you can write a simple bat file `C:\path\to\love --console C:\path\to\projectdir` to help make development smoother.

Comment: Thanks for that - yeah I gave zero brain a go, its sort of similar in that you have to tell zero brain which project directory to use. Its no big deal, I guess in c++ you always need to start with a main() so its no different really (I am a c++ guy normally).... just trying to figure out the options :)